# What is this item called on the table?

Tags: props, house-of-the-dragon

[image]

During a council meeting, each sitting minister brings a large jewel ball with them and slots them into a cradle to indicate presence and authority.

What is the proper name for them?

Comment: They do not appear in the books and have no real world equivalent, so there seems to be no _proper name_. Various articles refer to them simply as _balls_ or _orbs_, ex. [here](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/tv/tv-news/house-dragon-small-council-balls-explained-1235202056/).

Comment: There are several interviews with the set designers on the show, and not one of them ever gave them a proper name.  Just that they are meant as "punch-in cards" as on an old-school time clock.  If a person isn't present and hasn't "punched in", their ball goes to the middle of the table.  Sorta akin to most cinematic representations of King Arthur's Knights Of The Round Table, where they lay their swords on the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing i can think of is the [Globus cruciger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globus_cruciger) (sans the cruciger part).

A regalia frequently used in christian royalty.

The english name seems to be a [sovoreign's orb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_Jewels_of_the_United_Kingdom#Orbs), a simply an orb.